# File format identification

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, file-format, forensics

Does anyone know software for *File format identification*? I don't mean identification by file extension but by analyzing the byte stream. I would be interested in an open-source platform on which to develop.
Thanks

Comment: For what OS? On most Unix/Linux platforms, it ships with the core and is named `file`. Guessing by so-called "magics" (first-bytes of a file), not by extension.

Comment: For both Unix/Linux and Windows. Sorry, I haven't understood what You mean..

Comment: See the [file man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) for the Unix `file` command; you run this on the command-line. I didn't make this an answer now as it's not available for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DROID (Digital Record Object Identification)](https://github.com/digital-preservation/droid):

- Open source (Java, BSD)
- Perform automated batch identification of file formats.

[image: enter preformatted text here]